# SOLVED Problem with runnig a PHP fille locally, syntax error, unexpected end of file

Tags: php, html, xampp, localhost, blazy

Enabled short_open_tag in php.ini and now its working

Im trying to run simple blazy script locally with XAMPP
And I'm getting error that

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\gallery.php on line 61

It works perfectly fine on Mac with command `php -S 127.0.0.1:8000`

And I can't see any issue with the code, am I missing something? Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blazy/1.8.2/blazy.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>blazy test</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style type="text/css">
        .b-lazy {
           /**transform: scale(1);
           transition: all 500ms;
           opacity:0;**/
        }
        .b-loaded {
           transform: scale(1);
           opacity:1;
           width: 500px;
           height: 350px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        // set folder path
        $path = "images/";

        // count no. of images in dir
        $cnt = count(glob($path . "*.{jpg,jpeg}", GLOB_BRACE));

        if ($cnt > 0) {
            $fp = opendir($path);
            while ($image = readdir($fp)) {
                $ext = pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                $allowed_ext = ['jpg', 'jpeg'];
                if (in_array($ext, $allowed_ext)) {
                    $image_path = $path . $image; ?>    
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <img 
                    class="b-lazy image-wrapper" 
                    src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" 
                    data-src="<?php echo $image_path; ?>" 
                    alt="<?php echo $image; ?>" />
                </div>
                <? }
            }
            closedir($fp);
        } else {
            echo "Sorry! No images available in gallery!";
        }
        ?>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blazy/1.8.2/blazy.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            ;(function() {
                var bLazy = new Blazy();
            })();
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `<?php` instead of your one `<?`? "short open tag" might be disabled in your `php.ini` (and might be enabled on your Mac)

Comment: Thank you! Enabled short tags and its working now!

Comment: Nice. The strange thing is though that replacing `<?` with `<?php` didn't work.